# codeigniter: if 'null' value set to 0

Tags: php, codeigniter, null

in the code is all that I want, the file is a controller, or I should do the operation in the model?

```
public function newUser(){
    $param['name'] = $this->input->post("name");
    $param['email'] = $this->input->post("email");
    $param['user'] = $this->input->post("user");
    $param['password'] = sha1($this->input->post("password"));
    $param['state'] = $this->input->post("state"); //<-- this value is a checkbox, if is unckecked the value became 'null'. What I want is to change that 'null' value to 0 before to send to the database.

    $this->mdatabase->newUser($param);
}
```

Thanks :D .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `isset` we can check if the variable is set to any value, or is null.  Then from there, we can apply logic to assign your values accordingly.

```
 public function newUser(){
        $param['name'] = $this->input->post("name");
        $param['email'] = $this->input->post("email");
        $param['user'] = $this->input->post("user");
        $param['password'] = sha1($this->input->post("password"));
        if(!isset($param['state'])
           $param['state'] = 0;
        else if(isset($param['state'])
           $param['state'] = $this->input->post("state");

        $this->mdatabase->newUser($param);
    }
```

Should do  the trick for you.  Let me know  how it works.

**Edit**: Had a syntax error.  Should work now.

Comment: It works me like this: 
  $param['state'] = $this->input->post("state");
  if(!isset($param['state'])){ $param['state'] = 0; }
Thanks :D